# CSS Slideshow Displaying Inside A Container. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Goal:

To have a slideshow in this frame.

Here's a jsfiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/kf3cqk6y/2/

```css
$slides:4;
 $time_per_slide:4;
 $total_animation_time:$time_per_slide * $slides;
 body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-top-color: #856036;
  border-left-color: #5d4426;
  border-bottom-color: #856036;
  border-right-color: #5d4426;
  position: relative;
}
.photo {
  position: absolute;
  animation: round # {
    $total_animation_time
  }
  s infinite;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@for $index from 1 to $slides + 1 {
  img: nth-child(# {
    $index
  }
  ) {
    animation-delay: # {
      $total_animation_time - $time_per_slide * $index
    }
    s
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8517/8562729616_35b1384aa1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8562523343_9bb49b7b7b.jpg" alt="" />

  </div>

</body>
```

Question:

- How do I have the images display in the container?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the fiddle styling to be `scss` not `css`

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/a8ztyx8p/)

And if you want to include it in your web page, [use the code from this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/abouv3mr/)

Comment: Thank you @Darren ! How would I insert both of these in my home page?

Comment: Updated answer @Evon

Comment: Thanks again, @Darren ! The slideshow is functional on my page. Yet the image is halfway to the right of the frame when I added it to my page. What do you think the reason is for that?

Comment: Thats impossible to answer without seeing all of your page code - add all your code to the fiddle

Comment: Going to sleep on it. I'll post what I find in the morning. Thanks again @Darren.

Comment: Got it, @Darren. It was my <center> tag's position. It was outside of the <font> tag. Properly placed it, and it's looking great. Thanks for all your help. God bless!

Comment: do you have an idea of how I'd center the image inside of the container?